# Start programs synchronized in bash

Tags: multithreading, bash, synchronization

What I simply want to do is to do a wait for release lock.

I have for example 4 (because I have 4 core) identical script that works each on a part of a project each script looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
./prerenderscript $1
scriptsync step1 4
./renderscript $1
scriptsync step2 4
./postprod $1
```

when I run the main script that call the four script, I want each script to work individualy but at some point, I want to have each script waiting for each other because the next part need all data from the first part.

For now I used some logic like the number of file or a file that get created for each process and their existance getting tested with other one.

I also got the idea to use a makefile and to have

```
prerender%: source
  ./prerender $@
renderscript%: prerender1 prerender2 prerender3 prerender4
  ./renderscript $@
postprod: renderscript1 renderscript2 renderscript3 renderscript4
  ./postprod $@
```

But actually the process is simplified here the script is more complex and for each step the thread need to keep his variables.

Is there anyway to get the script in sync instead of the placeholder command scriptsync.

Comment: I would use a python script as a wrapper and work with `threading`. This way, I could re-use my shell scripts and benefit from pythons `threading` and other features.

Comment: @ansi_lumen: `threading` is not always appropriate in `python` because of the GIL, it depends on the workload.

Comment: @cdarke. True. One could still use `multiprocessing` and do real processes, if `threading` doesn't scale well. Main idea was to use an environment that handles threading/forking more convenient than `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in Bash, one way to do it is using inter-process communication to cause a task to wait for the previous one to finish.  Here is an example.

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 is received to allow for an example command, not required for the mechanism suggested
task_a()
{
# Do some work
sleep $1 # This is just a dummy command as an example
echo "Task A/$1 completed" >&2
# Send status to stdin, telling next task to proceed
echo "OK"
}

task_b()
{
IFS= read status ; [[ $status = OK ]] || return 1
# Do some work
sleep $1 # This is just a dummy command as an example
echo "Task B/$1 completed" >&2
}

task_a 2 | task_b 2 &
task_a 1 | task_b 1 &
wait
```

You will notice that the `read` could be anywhere in task B, so you could do some work, then wait (`read`) for the other task, then continue.  You could have many signals sent by task A to task B, and several corresponding `read` statements.

As shown in the example, you can launch several pipelines in parallel.

One limit of this approach is that a pipeline establishes a communication channel between one writer and one reader.  If a task needs to wait for signals from several tasks, you would need FIFOs to allow the task with dependencies to read from multiple sources.